# Powershell and Microsoft Word bookmarks and cells

Tags: vba, function, powershell, ms-word, bookmarks

So here's one for ya, a bit complicated (I think).

I have a document template, shown to below:
[image: word_cells]

I have a storage function and call shown below:
Function (a bit ugly):

```
function storage
{
param([string]$CompName)
Get-WmiObject win32_volume -ComputerName $CompName -Filter "DriveType=3 AND Label <> 'System Reserved' AND DriveLetter IS NOT NULL" | Sort-Object DriveLetter | ForEach-Object{"{0}, {1} - {2}gb `n" -f $_.Name,$_.Label,([Math]::Truncate($_.Capacity/1GB))}
}
```

Call:

```
#Storage input
Write-Host "...writing Storage"
$objRange = $wordDoc.Bookmarks.Item("storage").Range
$objRange.Text = storage -CompName $computer
$wordDoc.Bookmarks.Add("storage",$objRange) | Out-Null
```

Now as it stands, it half works.  It pumps out the values in the correct format meaning the query works and the bookmark in Word is correct, but all of the drives are placed in a single, stretch out cell.  My issue now is that I would like to have each drive appear in it's own cell  (largest column) within the template.  Right now, I have the Word bookmark 'storage' placed in the large cell immediately to the right of 'Storage'.

Is there a way to place each string of drive into it's own cell systematically?  Is this possible?  Furthermore (if this is doable), is there a way to auto-add rows based on needs within the code?  Say I have a server like this with a C: - G: while another server has simply a C: and D:.  Is it possible to start the template with a single row there and add more as needed from the code?

What current entry looks like:

[image: current_entries]

What I would like it to look like:

[image: preferred]

Thank you!

Comment: will be some Word-VBA solution helpful for you? I could show how to do it in VBA and you would try to convert it to powershell.

Comment: It would be a start.  I'm still not sure if what I need is entirely feasible.

Answer (score 0):

As agreed in comments, there are some tips based on Word-VBA for active document. Hope this will help to make a step forward.

**Before**
[image]

**A)** to add information in the cell below cell where your `storage bookmark is located`:

```
    Sub text_to_cell_below_bookmark()

        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("storage").Range.Next( _
        wdCell, _
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("storage").Range.Tables(1).Columns.Count _
                ).Text = "your storage information in the cell below"
    End Sub
```

**After**
[image]

**B)** to add additional row below the cell with bookmark:

```
    Sub additional_row_below_bookmark()

    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("storage").Range.Tables(1).Rows.Add _
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("storage").Range.Tables(1).Rows( _
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Storage").Range.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber) + 1)
    End Sub
```

**Edit** how to get row and column of cell in table where your bookmark is located:

```
Dim bmRow, bmCol
'to get row
bmRow = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("storage").Range.Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)
'to get column
bmCol = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("storage").Range.Information(wdEndOfRangeColumnNumber)
```

Comment: Thanks.  So for B, where does the wdEndOfRangeRowNumbers variable come from?  Also, what is the (1) in reference to after Tables?

Comment: `Tables(1)` refers to the only table where your bookmark is currently in. `Information(wdEndOfRangeRowNumber)`- this is a kind document information which return some parameters of document, like table row number where your bookmark is in.

Comment: So I'm nearly there.  Is there a way to get the coordinates of an object within a table?  For example, the coordinates of the "storage" bookmark item within the table...

Comment: This is proving much more difficult than the first part.  I can't translate this to PShell.  Not asking you to do it, just thinking out loud really...

Comment: Got it!  Will post my updated code either tonight or tomorrow.  Have some family stuff to do today.

Thanks for the help Kaz!